# Namespace management with Web References

Tags: web-services, namespaces

I have a seemingly simple goal, but I'm tripping over namespace issues.  I wrote a sharepoint web service client class, called sharepoint.cs, and it has its own namespace.  I want to re-use this class in other applications.  The problem is it needs to reference a web service reference.  Right now, when I add a web reference to the project, it adds it to the top level namespace, and the only way I can use it in my class is to reference this top-level namespace in my class.  That means every project in which I use this class, I need to change this reference to whatever top-level namespace my project is using.  There must be a way to write a portable web service class.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this simply by putting the sharepoint class in its own project.  Then I can set the references at this project level, and any other solution can simply include this project in their solution.